# android studio Gradle sync failed: Don't know how to build models for org.gradle.tooling.internal.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I opened a android studio file from class and tried to sync it but it says that the build was successful but gradle sync failed
the event log just says
Gradle sync failed: Don't know how to build models for org.gradle.tooling.internal.gradle.DefaultGradleBuild@4217e665

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. It seems like the latest version of Android Studio(3.6) has a new incompatible Gradle API. I fixed it installing Android Studio 3.5.3 and reimporting the project.